# Excel Macro adding value to cells

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask for some help regarding Excel macros.

I have a column full of data, and I want to create a macro that when i run it, it adds "1" to each cell in that column, instead of having to type "1" in all 300 cells. Any suggestions?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To **place a "1"** in the cells:

```
Sub Place1()
    Range("A1:A300").Value = 1
End Sub
```

To **add "1" to the current value** in the cells:

```
Sub Add1()
    For Each r In Range("A1:A300")
        r.Value = r.Value + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```